# CPP - Async not working with DLL and C-Sharp

Tags: c#, c++, asynchronous, dll

I want to read asynchronously on serial port from Csharp by calling method in DLL. Please go through the simple code below.

CSharp Project:

```
[DllImport("SerialTry.dll")]
public static extern void connectDevice();

static void Main(string[] args) {
  connectDevice();
  Console.WriteLine("Printed after reading 50 bytes connectDevice() - WHY?");
}
```

DLL Project:

```
void connectDevice(){
    //Reads 50 Bytes and print byte number from serial port async
    auto result = std::async(std::launch::async, &DeviceControlActivity::read_data, this, std::ref(my_serial));
    cout << "Printing before reading 50 Bytes - EXPECTED!\n";
}
```

```
Output: 
Printing before reading 50 Bytes - EXPECTED!
#1 #2 #3 .... #50
Printed after reading 50 bytes connectDevice() - WHY?
```

```
Expected:
Printing before reading 50 Bytes - EXPECTED!
Printed after reading 50 bytes connectDevice() - WHY?
#1 #2 #3 .... #50
```

Answer (score 1):

`std::async` returns a `std::future` object. From the [documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/future/%7Efuture) of the destructor:

> std::future::~future
>
> these actions will not block for the shared state to become ready, **except that it may block if all of the following are true: the shared state was created by a call to std::async, the shared state is not yet ready, and this was the last reference to the shared state**.

emphasis mine. From what I can tell all of these conditions are true in your example.

Edit:
I'm not at all familiar with std::async, but from reading the documentation it seem similar to [Task.Run](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.run?view=net-5.0). If so it should be fairly simple to do a synchronous call to the c++ code and deal with the async-stuff on the c# side.

Comment: Do you suggest any other approach if not async/future?

Comment: @suraj Jorwekar added a section about task.run.

Comment: Adding async to C# is one way to do but for some reason, I don't want to add any async/task/thread login on to the C# side and handle purely in CPP.

Comment: Also, I tried using std::thread and the results are the same whereas detaching [thread1.detach()] the thread gives the expected output but ends abruptly with no serial read to which I assume DLLMain is responsible as threads destructor.